# Валидатор php в php?

Tags: php, парсер

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос такой. Сразу оговорюсь - чистый интерес, но может кому и практически пригодится. В общем, решаема ли такая задача: взять код(файл/бд/переменная, не важно) и **если он валидный** выполнить(eval)?

Т.е. вопрос именно в проверке, можно ли как-то средствами php проверить переменную на содержание рабочего/синтаксически верного кода?

```
<?
$code = file_get_contents('very.suspicious.code.php');
if (isValidPhpCode($code)) {
  eval('?'.'>'.$code.'<'.'?');
  } else echo '<p><b>Error:</b> code is invalid</p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Валидность синтаксиса можно проверить через консольную комманду `php -l`

```
$file = 'very.suspicious.code.php';
$cmd = 'php -l '.escapeshellarg($file).' 2>&1 >/dev/null';
exec($cmd, $errors, $return);

if ($return === 0) {
    // no syntax errors
} else {
    echo implode("\n", $errors)."\n";
}
```

Или если код содержится в переменной, то через pipe'ы

```
function check_syntax($code, $withoutOpenTag = false, &$error = null) {
    if ($withoutOpenTag) {
        $code = '<?php '.$code;
    }

    $spec = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
        1 => array('file', '/dev/null', 'w'),
        2 => array('pipe', 'w')
    );

    $proc = proc_open('php -l', $spec, $pipes);

    fwrite($pipes[0], $code);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    return proc_close($proc) === 0;
}

$code = '$a = 1 2;';
if (check_syntax($code, true, $error)) {
    // no syntax errors
} else {
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Я еще и сам снизошел до погугления, добавлю к ответу вот сие: http://mrkto.com/php-syntax-check/ Видимо, теперь все варианты разобраны)